# Taking a camera picture causes page reload or tab crash

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, camera

I have page when I have to attach 8 photos, from camera or from memory. When I'm opening camera in firefox (android) by html:

```
<input
  data-category="5"
  class="file-camera-input"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  capture="camera"
/>
```

And when I capture the photo my page will refresh or crash will crash. I thinking it is problem with memory ram on device because in logcat I expect it will allocate approx 3gb ram when I open camera but it happens just on firefox. Maybe whose know how to handle it?